apt-cacher-ng fails with error 500 Remote or cache error with https jfrog repo
We have jfrog debian repo named like test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr
We using apt-cacher-ng to build local cache and mirror:
apt-get update with source file having pointed to apt-cacher-ng proxy is failing with below error.
root@test-server:/etc/apt# sudo apt-get update
Ign:1 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy InRelease
0% [Waiting for headers]
0% [Waiting for headers]
0% [Waiting for headers]
Ign:2 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy-updates InRelease
Ign:1 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy InRelease
Ign:2 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy-security InRelease
Ign:3 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy-updates InRelease
Err:1 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy InRelease
  500  Remote or cache error [IP: 127.0.0.1 3142]
Err:2 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy-security InRelease
  500  Remote or cache error [IP: 127.0.0.1 3142]
Err:3 http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr jammy-updates InRelease
  500  Remote or cache error [IP: 127.0.0.1 3142]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/dists/jammy/InRelease  500  Remote or cache error [IP: 127.0.0.1 3142]
W: Failed to fetch http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/dists/jammy-security/InRelease  500  Remote or cache error [IP: 127.0.0.1 3142]
W: Failed to fetch http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/dists/jammy-updates/InRelease  500  Remote or cache error [IP: 127.0.0.1 3142]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.

Since the remote jfrog repo is https, Following is the source file is used
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64 allow-insecure=yes] http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/ jammy main restricted
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64 allow-insecure=yes] http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/ jammy-security main restricted
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64 allow-insecure=yes] http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/ jammy-updates main restricted

deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64 allow-insecure=yes] http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/ jammy universe
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64 allow-insecure=yes] http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/ jammy-security universe
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64 allow-insecure=yes] http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/ jammy-updates universe

deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64 allow-insecure=yes] http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/ jammy multiverse
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64 allow-insecure=yes] http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/ jammy-security multiverse
deb [trusted=yes arch=amd64 allow-insecure=yes] http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/ jammy-updates multiverse

When I use source file without apt-cacher-ng port then it works fine. When I use source file as above, it fails.
Following are the logs using curl
# when we connect to artifactory directly with curl, it works 
root@test-server:/etc/apt# curl   -I  https://test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/dists/jammy/InRelease
HTTP/1.1 200
Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2024 10:54:56 GMT
Content-Type: application/octet-stream
Content-Length: 8097
Connection: keep-alive
X-JFrog-Version: Artifactory/7.100.2 80002900
X-Artifactory-Id: 9d02eeaaaf809a37c50c7a3da842eadd051dc3a5
X-Artifactory-Node-Id: b0vzfxk5psc7e-artifactory-primary-2
Last-Modified: Tue, 17 Dec 2024 04:18:00 GMT
ETag: ae46463afa4be172bafc87c5d467010d69115889
X-Checksum-Sha1: ae46463afa4be172bafc87c5d467010d69115889
X-Checksum-Sha256: bab499e91c23883665c23e1428caa9c26439f09bf2f28489c544a4bdfe595cb2
X-Checksum-Md5: 5160272608473cc9c570671c7ce7e6cb
Accept-Ranges: bytes
X-Artifactory-Filename: InRelease
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="InRelease"; filename*=UTF-8''InRelease
Cache-Control: no-store
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains
X-Request-ID: 39716a4b319deecbc0088cabffcb74e6

#when using artifactory repo with apt-cacher as proxy it fails 
root@test-server:/etc/apt# curl -I  http://localhost:3142/HTTPS///test-jfrog.net/artifactory/gateway-ubuntu-arch-debian-vr/dists/jammy/InRelease
HTTP/1.1 500 Remote or cache error
Content-Length: 484
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 17 Dec 2024 10:56:36 GMT
Server: Debian Apt-Cacher NG/3.7.4

